# How to arrange files in separate folder monthwise according to "date modified" [Windows 7]?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a mega folder that contains a lot of files, like a dozen created per day. How to arrange them files in a separate folder month-wise according to "date modified" [Windows 7]? I need to do this to create online backups that are easy to access, in chunks of month-wise folders. I understand there might be some method using the command prompt but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying into the question as text. If you do not have any code and need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 1):

more a finger exercise than a real challenge.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
  set "month=%%~ta"
  set "month=!month:~3,2!"  ;this is dependent on your locale date format
  ECHO md !month! 2>nul
  ECHO move "%%a" !month!\
)
```

remove the both `ECHO` commands, if the output is what you need.

Note: this is a literal answer to your question (sort by month). I'll leave the marginal adaptions to take also the year into account.